# Using if conditions at the end of a FOR loop in Batch

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop

I have a simple for loop in a batch file I'm working on but I can't get the variables to expand correctly.  the whole script is below..

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set track=0

FOR /f "tokens=2" %%G IN ('find "PhysicalTrackNumber" %1') DO if %track% LSS %%G set track=%%G

echo %track%

echo %1

pause
```

The for command pulls all the rows with the physical track number and I'm just trying to get the biggest number.  IT always stays 0 though when it's comparing.  I've tried with !! around my variable as well but then the script seems to do something completely different.  I thought it would take the new variable.

What am I missing to compare the outputs to the previous and just get the biggest number?

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion) since you are writing and reading the same variable within a block of code like a `for` loop...

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use the exclamations for your variables to use delayed expansion.

Comment: `{FOR /f "tokens=2" %%G IN ('find "PhysicalTrackNumber" %1') DO (if !track! LSS %%G set track=%%G)}

`


 Above is how I added the exclamations. Since that is the value I want to be the largest. But it completely changes the way the script works and doesn't even compare the numbers, so I must be doing it wrong, but I can't quite get the syntax to work right.

Comment: I'm finding that if use !track!, then I find some how my final echo output is showing that %track% has actually become the parameter.

So echo %track% actually is showing the %1 output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`find "string" filename` output](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) consists of

- an empty line;
- a string of 10 dashes followed by the filename being searched line;
- any matching lines of text in the file.

Use [`skip=2` option](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) (a  number of lines to skip at the beginning):

```
FOR /f "skip=2 tokens=2" %%G IN ('find "PhysicalTrackNumber" "%~1"') DO (
    if !track! LSS %%G set "track=%%~G"
)
```

As an alternative, use [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) instead of `find`:

```
FOR /f "tokens=2" %%G IN ('findstr "PhysicalTrackNumber" "%~1"') DO (
    if !track! LSS %%G set "track=%%~G"
)
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!

I did not catch the initial empty line and issues that was causing.  I haven't had to use the skip option before and this was a great lesson in that.  I originally had findstr but changed it for another reason which I see now was fruitless.  I'm just using the bottom version for the simplicity but understanding the skip option really is a huge help.

Comment: @Raxler If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted. [See this page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/) for an explanation of why this is important.